# Add Expires headers For Google Fonts In .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, google-fonts, gtmetrix

How to add Add Expires headers For This `Google Font`  
`https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400,600,700,800,900|Poppins:300,400,500,600,700,800,900&display=swap`

is it possible to Add Expires headers in `.htaccess`

[Screenshot From GTMETRIX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x1FIB.png)

sorry for my bad language

Comment: Unless you have control over the google fonts server I fail to see how you want to manipulate a request to _their_ server...

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the headers for requests you're not responding to. In this case, the browser will make a request to Google asking for fonts. The browser will receive a response from Google(not you) with headers(cache, encoding, etc) and body(actual resource).

Don't forget these tools point you in the right direction but are not always aware of the whole picture. When you share resources with other sites, the user may already have the requested resources cached.